# Set current working directory on ssh

Tags: ssh

I am trying to ssh from one machine to another within a Python script (Nautilus script). It works with the following:

```
ssh -t user@server "cd /home/some/dir ; csh"
```

However I don't like the idea of hardcoding the shell type.

Is there a way to set `cwd` within the ssh command without the need to hardcode the shell type?

Comment: Technically it was a `python` script ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593570/how-to-make-ssh-go-directly-to-specific-directory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Invoke `$SHELL` instead.

```
ssh -t user@server 'cd /home/some/dir ; exec "$SHELL"'
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do this like so...

```
ssh -t user@server "cd /home/some/dir ; bash"
```

Where `bash` is your desired shell.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there a way to auto-detect or ommit shell, so it go to default? I don't like the idea to hardcode it.

Comment: @umpiresky: I don't have an Ubuntu box on which to test this, but on *BSD I can do: `ssh -t user@server "cd /home/some/dir ; login user"` (where user is the username that you have provided to ssh). If your remote host has the same setup as localhost you could use ${SHELL} instead. YMMV.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Nope, login user ddn't work for me. I'm connecting from Ubuntu to FreeBSD, but it would be nice to work for any server. That's why I don't like the idea to hardcode shell type (csh in my case).

Comment: `login user` works for me on FreeBSD.

Comment: Hm, strange, for me terminal crashes after I provuide password.

Comment: @umpiresky: You included the '`-t`'?

Comment: @Johnsyweb  Yes.

Comment: @umpiresky. Then I am stuck. I suggest migrating the question to http://askubuntu.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ . Someone there will know!

Comment: Hm, maybe, yes. But we already have a working nautilus script, lets just make it better. Thank fou your valuable help.