# ssh and cd into current directory

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, remote

When I `ssh` into `mycomputer` from `logincomputer`, I would like to automatically `cd` into the current directory (the one from which the `ssh` command was executed) on `mycomputer`. In particular:

```
> cd /tmp/
```

Now `/tmp/` is the current working directory.

```
> ssh mycomputer
> cd /tmp
```

I would like this to happen automatically with 1 command. Is this possible? Assume the directory structure is exactly the same on both computers.

Comment: ..and what happens if the directory only exists on `mycomputer` and not `logincomputer`?

Comment: edited to reflect your comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set current working directory on ssh](http://superuser.com/questions/290544/set-current-working-directory-on-ssh)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626533/how-can-i-ssh-directly-to-a-particular-directory

Answered on Stack Overflow.

`ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd /directory_wanted"`

You could add this into a shell script:

`ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd  \$PWD; bash"`

Comment: great, what does dirname and 0 do?

Comment: also why not: `ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd $(pwd); bash"`

Comment: @Alex I'm not very proficient in the way of BASH scripting, but I would assume `$dirname $0` would return to path to where you currently are within the local system.

Comment: @Alex I got the second part from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242538/unix-shell-script-find-out-which-directory-the-script-file-resides but it sounds like $(pwd) should be able to do the same thing.

Comment: ok, cool. i think the version you provide won't work.. that's the output of executing:
`>echo $(dirname $0)`
`.`

Comment: it returns "." . i would suggest changing your answer to `$(pwd)` .. that seems to work fine. i'll accept once you do.

Comment: you don't need the "/" its just `$(pwd)`

Comment: You can simplify your command and avoid imposing a specific shell with `ssh -t ... "cd $PWD;$0"`

Comment: I take that back. This does not seem to work. It did when I suggested this but nt currenlty... not sure what changed.

Comment: My $HOME changes from system to system, and this gets me to the same subdirectory `alias devt='dev -t "cd ${PWD/$HOME/\$HOME}; $SHELL --login"'` (where `dev` is another alias that invokes ssh with a bunch of options I need).  I'm not sure how you would correctly escape the $'s in a shell function.

Answer (score 2):

I'd propose adding the following line to your `.bashrc` file:

```
sshcd() { ssh -t "$@" "cd '$(pwd)'; bash -l"; }
```

Then you can ssh into the remote host using

```
sshcd mycomputer
```

Passing ssh options also works as expected, e.g. to specify a different port:

```
sshcd mycomputer -p 2222`
```

Break down how it works:

```
sshcd() {         \ # Define a function called sshcd
  ssh -t          \ # ssh and get remote pty although a command is given
    "$@"          \ # Pass all options from sshcd to ssh
    "cd '$(pwd)'; \ # Get the local directory using pwd, cd to it remotely
     bash -l";    \ # Then start a login shell on the remote host
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this:

```
ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cd \$PWD; bash"
```

Comment: using single quotes, no need to escape the variable